# how to select a picture from UIImagePickerController using Frank Cucumber?

Tags: ios, cucumber, uiimagepickercontroller, bdd

I was trying to use BDD technique to check the import picture process using [Frank](https://github.com/moredip/Frank/) in the iPhone Simulator.

The problem is that I cannot call the last step of selecting an image from UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary source (launching the UIImagePickerController was very easy using "touch"-commands on a button).

It always stuck in the progress when I can see the saved images in the Simulator. The Frank Symbiote said the object I wanna touch is a "PLAlbumViewCell" object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just sorted this out today, basically PLAlbumView inherits from UITableView so I created a custom step definition to select the first photo.

```
When /^I select the first photo$/ do
  frankly_map( "tableView", "touchx:y:", '10', '10' )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
images = frankly_map( "view:'PUPhotosGridCell'", 'tag' )
  if images.count > 0
    touch ("view:'PUPhotosGridCell' first")
  end
```

I have used above lines of code to select first image from UIImagePickerController.