# how to do swipe/scroll gesture automatically with Frank Cucumber?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, cucumber, bdd

I was using BDD technique on my current iOS project. Now I have some scrollviews where I wanna automatically scroll to target point.

Is there a way to imitate "scrollRectToVisible:animated" using [Frank](https://github.com/moredip/Frank/) or to do a swipe/scroll gesture?

I already checked [Frank Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/frank-discuss/iqVz7cKs3NI). But there are no working results for it.

For anybody looking for the touch Gesture using Frank:
[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412603/how-to-select-a-picture-from-uiimagepickercontroller-using-frank-cucumber)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old, but still...

You can use `scroll_view_to_bottom`. (See [here](https://github.com/moredip/Frank/blob/master/gem/lib/frank-cucumber/scroll_helper.rb)). Unfortunatelly there's no way to scroll automatically.